# Creating new razor views after compiling and publishing an asp.net core app?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Is it possible to create new razor view pages after you have compiled and published the app? For example:
A function that runs a cli command like dotnet new page or dotnet new view?

Trying to create an application that will have a web gui that will allow for the creation of new pages. I can do this with scripting languages, but I'm unfamiliar with how to do this in asp.net core. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It possible, but we don't suggest you do such things.

As far as I know, asp.net core is build based on C# and is a compile language. We don't suggest you compile and publish it at server side.

As you know after you use the command, you need to have some permission for this application and the backend code logic may have more permission, it will caused a lot of security problem.

If you want to create a new page, I suggest you could consider using the Js and html page to do the same things.